# Removing extra space at start in bash

Tags: php, regex, bash, awk, sed

I am trying to get the `extension_dir` and store it in a variable

`php -i | grep extension_dir` gives

`extension_dir => /usr/lib64/php/modules => /usr/lib64/php/modules` as output

I want to store   `/usr/lib64/php/modules` in a variable

This is what i tried
`php -i | grep extension_dir | cut -d'>' -f3` gives `/usr/lib64/php/modules`

How can i remove the space at the start

I welcome any cleaner solution

Comment: You can try this .`sed 's/\(.*\) => \(.*\) => \(.*\)/\2/'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `awk` instead of `cut`:

```
php -i | grep extension_dir | awk -F '=> ' '{print $3}'
```

Even grep can be removed using awk:

```
php -i | awk -F '=> ' '/extension_dir/{print $3}'
```

Comment: And to store it in a variable: `var=$(php -i | awk -F '=> ' '/extension_dir/{print $3}')`

Answer (score 2):

With **sed:**

```
php -i | grep extension_dir | sed 's/.* => //'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
php -i | sed -n '/extension_dir/ s/.*=> *//p'
```

a simple sed is enough (or awk), no need of a grep in the middle

Answer (score 0):

your command line

```
php -i | grep extension_dir | cut -d '>' -f3
```

can be modified to

```
php -i | grep extension_dir | cut -d '>' -f3|cut -c 2-
```

cuts from the second character ignoring the first character which is a space